# How to I ensure that a type is inside an array?

Tags: typescript

If I have an array like:

```
const MyArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and a function like

```
const MyArrayPrinter = (value) => console.log(value)
```

Is it possible for me to ensure the function argument is a value that exists inside the array at compile time?

for example:

```
 const MyArrayPrinter = (value: existsin MyArrayPrinter) => console.log(value)
```

Comment: what about using typescript enums instead of the array? will that satisfy your requirement? they can be used as types

Comment: A bit weird. Your question is about types, description about values. Which one you want to check?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if the array is defined at compile time. You can define it as a readonly tuple using [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) (which will ensure that literal types are not widened) and query/lookup its value type:

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] as const;

type Value = typeof myArray[number]; // 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6

const myArrayPrinter = (value: Value) => console.log(value)

myArrayPrinter(10) // Argument of type '10' is not assignable to parameter of type '1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoCMANDAEwkDMJALCQKwkBsAujOhDKJFANwBQfKAgAOAUxgA1dABsAruNxCxIAGbxkaTHjCy4AI1EpmPGAHpTMAjAA+ZGzAr3q9uvcYCu0dagwIACigAlmBQhjgwABQAbjLyAFySsaIAlDgAfJzgECDSogB00iAA5tFJyQKIPpgBwaEoEQQADKnmMKhFuqIhMKowSuIA5E0DMIEcYCCw7BCBRWDoerl9IDDC6BhwonU9av0wQ-ak9o62zrautowDeUA)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. You need simple code instead your fantasy typescript:

```
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const myArrayPrinter = (value) => {
  if (myArray.includes(value)) {
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

TypeScript is using for types checkup. Values checking should be in runtime:

```
  const myArray: Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  const myArrayPrinter = (value: number) => {
    if (myArray.includes(value)) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a question about checking a type at compile time. See @AlekseyL.'s answer.